# Texto que se alinea hacia la derecha

Tags: html, css

Tengo un texto dentro de un div pero sucede que cuando este da el salto de linea se mueve hacia la derecha

```
<div style="width: 300px;"><b> aqui va el texto que cuando llega el momento de saltar linea se va hacia la derecha</b></div>
```

**¿como lo soluciono?**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y el css? porque debe haber un `text-align: right;` en alguna parte que hace que el texto vaya para la derecha, puedes hacer un `text-align: left !important;`, pero es necesario ver el css para ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar mover solo la caja a la derecha. En este ejemplo tienes

```css
  position: relative;
  right: calc(300px - 100vw);
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  right: calc(300px - 100vw);
}
```

```html
<div><b> aqui va el texto que cuando llega el momento de saltar linea se va hacia la derecha</b></div>
```

Otra posibilidad sería utilizar el viejo `float:right`:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div><b> aqui va el texto que cuando llega el momento de saltar linea se va hacia la derecha</b></div>
```

Espero que sea lo que necesites.